# Binance Spot TestNet is not updating prices using API client

Tags: python, bots, trading, cryptocurrency

I am trying to build a trading bot in Python using Binance API.

In the testnet, I was able to work until yesterday when orderbook and ticker API's started giving me frozen prices. I am not a direct client to Binance so cannot confirm the issue directly with Binance. Please someone confirm the same issue as I haven't seen any announcement on Binance official site. If it's a reoccurring issue, I will check with my client (whose account I am using) so he can ask Binance to fix it this issue.

FYI, prices (bid/ask) of LTC coin change every 5 to 10 seconds. At least a single penny (0.01) up or down which I will show down below:

Here is a small portion of a long log shows that price is frozen. Ticker vs Orderbook way they are different from each other but they are frozen to their own values. Like OrderBook (bid/ask) are frozen to 64.18 and 64.1 while Ticker values are frozen to 64.1 and 64.18.

It clearly seems to be a problem and a blocker.

**TestNet result:**

> 2023-09-20 13:26:49,158 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:27:00,580 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:00,580 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.18, new ask:64.1  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:01,213 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:01,213 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.1, new ask:64.18  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:01,213 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:27:11,742 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:11,742 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.18, new ask:64.1  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:12,374 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:12,375 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.1, new ask:64.18  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:12,375 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:27:22,855 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:22,855 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.18, new ask:64.1  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:23,796 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:23,796 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.1, new ask:64.18  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:27:23,796 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds

(Before you suggest a theory that prices are not changing because of unavailable matching prices, I can respond to that in advance. Binance is big exchange, even in the TestNet, there should be enough orders changing market price. However, I came to know from a source that TestNet prices should be always closer to the prices in Live. So prices should be changing in the Testnet regardless.)

I ran same code in **Spot Live** and guess what?
Prices are changing as expected.

> 2023-09-20 13:39:04,633 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:04,633 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.63, new ask:64.62  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:04,948 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:04,948 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.62, new ask:64.63  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:04,948 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:39:15,119 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:15,119 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.63, new ask:64.62  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:15,434 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:15,434 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.62, new ask:64.63  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:15,434 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:39:25,602 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:25,602 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.61, new ask:64.6  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:25,917 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:25,917 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.6, new ask:64.61  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:25,917 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:39:36,086 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:36,086 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.58, new ask:64.57  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:36,401 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:36,401 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.57, new ask:64.58  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:36,401 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds
> 2023-09-20 13:39:46,563 :: INFO ::  From orderbook:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:46,563 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.57, new ask:64.56  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:46,879 :: INFO ::  From Ticker:  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:46,879 :: INFO ::  ---------New bid: 64.56, new ask:64.57  ####
> 2023-09-20 13:39:46,879 :: INFO :: Wait for 10 seconds

```
while(True):
    order_book = client.get_order_book(symbol=symbol)
    new_bid = float(order_book['asks'][0][0])
    new_ask = float(order_book['bids'][0][0])
    
    logging.info(f" From orderbook:  ####")
    logging.info(f" ---------New bid: {new_bid}, new ask:{new_ask}  ####")
    
    ticker = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol=symbol)
    

    new_bid = float(ticker['bidPrice']) 
    new_ask = float(ticker['askPrice'])

    logging.info(f" From Ticker:  ####")
    logging.info(f" ---------New bid: {new_bid}, new ask:{new_ask}  ####")
                    
            
    logging.info(f"Wait for {pause_time} seconds")
    time.sleep(pause_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Spot testnet has it's own orderbook. If there is no change on the book, the best prices will not change. Some symbols have less trades than others. You could try BTCUSDT on testnet, it has more orders and great for test.